C# .NET8 web app: how can I route "bad" URLs to main page?
We've deprecated an old ASP.NET web site written in VB.NET. In its place, we've substituted a simple "banner page" written in C# on .NET 8.
The new app has

a main page, and
pages for adding, updating and deleting "feature requests".

It's written in C#, using .NET 8.  It's hosted on IIS/Windows Server 2019.
The original app had many different URLs. I'd like to ensure that users are always directed to the new "main" page, regardless of whatever "old" URL they're trying.
I had hoped to use IIS "configure error"; but that doesn't seem to work (I tried many variations).
So instead, I wrote a middleware component to redirect on HTTP 404.  It seems to work (I successfully redirect to the main page, regardless of URL). But I get this error:

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.

Code - RedirectPageNotFound.cs:
public class RedirectPageNotFound 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<RedirectPageNotFound> _logger;

    public RedirectPageNotFound(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RedirectPageNotFound> logger) 
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) 
    {
        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404) 
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Handling 404 error for request {context.Request.Path}");
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
        } 
        else 
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectPageNotFound>();

Q1: How can I fix the System.InvalidOperationException?
Q2: Is there a "better" way to re-route "bad URLs" to my "main page", so that it doesn't do an HTTP redirect at all?

For one thing, you absolutely should not have await _next(context); a second time. You haven't shown the stack trace so it's hard to say for sure, but my guess is that the exception is thrown when it tries to write the non-404 response from the second _next call, after having already successfully written it during the first _next call. In addition to posting the stack trace, set breakpoints and follow execution for non-404 cases, not just the 404 case.

Thank you.  You're absolutely correct.  I knew that was causing the InvalidOperationException ("The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.").  But it looked like I needed the first "await next(_context)" in order to get the "404" status code.

I resolved the problem by having my middleware check for "context.EndPoint == null" instead of "context.Response.StatusCode == 404":
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.GetEndpoint() == null)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            context.User.Identity.Name,
            context.Request.Path);
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open("user404.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                sw.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        context.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
}

